# db2 insert failure when ' present (even escaping doesn't work)

Tags: database, insert, db2

I am running an insert command on db2 like the following:

```
insert into uinfo.transaction (TRANSACTION_ID, DATE,TIME,ID,USER,DESC) values
(14,20110311,36909,97,2497580,'Note:9045-02 2=34 ///' 2eq034d,xw d""::: 214l 23e;l2')
```

It gave an error saying, During SQL processing it returned:

```
SQL0103N The numeric literal "2034d" is not valid. SQLSTATE=42604
```

So, I tried escaping the `'` as following:

```
insert into uinfo.transaction (TRANSACTION_ID, DATE,TIME,ID,USER,DESC) values
(14,20110311,36909,97,2497580,'Note:9045-02 2=34 ///\' 2eq034d,xw d""::: 214l 23e;l2')
```

It still fails saying the same thing. During SQL processing it returned:

```
SQL0103N The numeric literal "2034d" is not valid. SQLSTATE=42604
```

Any idea what is wrong above and can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include `'` in a string you need to double it. E.g.: `'ab''cd'`.
For details read the Character string constants section on http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000731.html.